# Client or Server to upload file go cloud?

Tags: react-native, architecture, gcloud

I have created a React Native application that requires a user to upload images. My current implementation involves the client creating a stream to the server and the server uploading the files to google cloud.

My server is written in Node.

I have tried uploading directly from client and then returning the gcloud url string to the server and the server then stores the url in the database. This way seemed faster and less verbose, however i am not sure that putting the extra data load on the client is recommended ? Also it results in a bigger client side build because of the google cloud library included to perform the uploads.(Which im pretty sure is only supposed to be used server side)

So is it better to send the file from the client to the server to be uploaded or directly upload the file to gcloud from the client ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You actually pointed out all the pros and cons of the alternatives in your question. I'd like to add one more point towards "uploading via server" option: it will be easier to scale.

For example, at one point you might want to use queuing system for your file uploads or any other way of load balancing and if all your uploads go through server - it will be backend-only issue, otherwise you would need to tweak your frontend also and load balancing itself would be much more cumbersome.

Another case is you moving from gcloud to something else - again, much less invasive to solve on backend.

I'd go with server-side uploads, keeping in mind that your traffic bill will grow bigger as you scale.